# Check if a thread is active

Tags: c++, multithreading

Need to add a thread check within the following wrapper :

```
class threadWrapper{
    private:
        std::thread m_thread;

    void set_sched_priority(const int sched, const int priority){
        sched_param sparam;
        sparam.sched_priority = priority;
        pthread_setschedparam(m_thread.native_handle(), sched, &sparam);
    }
    public:
    bool isActive(){
        //Dont know how to achieve this
    }

    template< class...Args > 
    explicit threadWrapper(const int sched, const int priority, Args&&... args):
    m_thread(std::forward<Args>(args)...)
    {
        set_sched_priority(sched, priority);
    };

    threadWrapper &operator=(threadWrapper&&) = default;
    threadWrapper &operator=(const threadWrapper&) = delete;
    threadWrapper(threadWrapper&) = delete;
    
    //Need to work on this:
    ~threadWrapper(){
        if(m_thread.joinable()) m_thread.join();
    }
};
```

I want to implement a function to check thread health `isActive()` and suspend thread execution `suspend()`.

1. Tried using `thread::joinable()` method, but it always returned true for `isActive()`.
2. Added future and promise object as private member variables:

```
//Constructor change 
explicit threadWrapper(const int sched, const int priority, Args&&... args):
   future(p.get_future()),.......
   
bool isActive(){
   return !(this->future.wait_for(0ms) == std::future_status::ready);
}
```

This didnt work as the function `isActive` always return true.
I am unsure how to proceed with the function implementation and none of the other resources I searched for were helpful

Comment: "_it always returned true_" - only if the thread is started and it's not detached or already joined. When should it return `false`?

Comment: XY problem. You don't suspend a thread from outside (unless you're writing the OS kernel), you synchronize threads by using synchronization mechanisms inside the threaded code.

Answer (score 0):

Just code what you need. The obvious way is to use two boolean flags protected by a mutex, one to indicate whether the thread is active or not and one to indicate whether the thread should suspend or not.

When the thread becomes inactive, it should acquire the mutex and set the active flag to false.

When the thread is at a point where it is safe to suspend, it should acquire the mutex and check the suspend flag.

To suspend the thread, acquire the mutex, check the active flag, and set the suspend flag.

If you need the thread to be able to wait until it is unsuspended, use a condition variable for that. If you need an outside thread to be able to wait until the thread has suspended, use another condition variable and a flag that the thread sets to true when it has suspended.

You really just code each feature you need however you want. These are the simplest ways, but they work just fine.